# Не могу использовать в C# Index и Range

Tags: c#, index, range

есть массив. Могу вывести 1, 2, 3... элементы. А выводить с конца используя ^1 ^2 не могу. Выдает 2 ошибки: Предопределенный тип "System.Index" не определен или не импортирован, Отсутствует обязательный для компилятора член "System.Index..ctor". И на 8 си шарпе, и на 11, и на разных версия .Net Framework, все равно не работает. Полный код:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] massiv = {1, 2, 3};
            Console.WriteLine(massiv[^1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Эта структура доступна только начиная с .NET Core 3 и дальше, на .NET Framework возможно оно и н должно работать.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь использовать что-то новое, в чем-то старом. .NET Framework устарел и умер, его не развивают, его заменили  современным .NET. Это ваша основная проблема. Не, если хотите натянуть сову на глобус, то [реализуйте новый функционал сами](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-use-csharp-8-indices-and-ranges-in-dotnet-standard-2-0-and-dotn.htm), но это весьма странно, тянуть в старую версию что-то новое, когда можно просто обновить проект, особенно, когда вы только начинаете разработку и вроде как изучение...

Comment: Index и Range появились в C# 8.0. И код работает

Comment: @rotabor поддержка этих классов в индексаторах появилась в C# 8.0, а сами классы в .NET Core 3.1. А автор использует устаревший Framework 4.x. Изменения только версии языка компилятора недостаточно. Версия BCL должна соответствовать. То есть автору достаточно создать проект нарример под .NET 6, и всё заработает само.

Comment: @aepot ? Я как бы ничего и не спрашивал. Вы можете адресовать свои ответы прямо автору вопроса, не обязательно их передавать через меня, что вы, собственно, и сделали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы индексаторы `Index` и `Range` работали, проект должен быть создан под .NET Core 3.1 или новее (.NET 5, 6, 7, 8, и т.д.). Версию C# при этом менять вручную не требуется.